# Expected Value for distinct substrings of length $k$

Tags: expected-value, biology

Genomes consist of 4 nucleobases (A, C, G, T). If we take genome substrings of length $k$ (called $k$-mers), we have $4^k$ *theoretically possible* substrings. If we have a genome of length $l$ (meaning $l$ nucleobases), we will have a total of $l - (k - 1)$ substrings. If we now randomly take $l - (k - 1)$ substrings from these $4^k$ *theoretically possible* substrings, what is the expected value for?:

- the number of *unique* substrings (occur exactly once)
- the number of *distinct* substrings (occur once or more)
- the number of *recurring* substrings (occur at least twice)

To simplify the question: If you have $n$ numbers and take $m$ numbers from these ($n>m$; numbers can be chosen several times), what is the expected value / amount of numbers from these $m$ chosen numbers that occur only once/once or more/at least twice.

Thank you!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I strongly suspect you are expected to assume independence; that each substring is equally probable to be the one of interest.  That simplifies the calculation considerably.  Now a Poisson distribution is an excellent approximation.